# Show that every open set in second countable LCH space is $\sigma$-compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a second countable, locally compact Hausdorff space.

> Theorem:
>
> If $S \in \tau$, then $S$ is $\sigma$-compact.

How do I show this statement? The following is what I have tried:

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a countable base for $(X,\tau)$. For each $x \in S$ there exists a compact neighbourhood $V(x), x \in V(x) \subseteq S$.(This is a theorem that I'm allowed to use) Then $S = \bigcup_{x \in S} V(x)$, but how do I show that there exists a finite cover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict to compact neighborhoods of the form $\overline V$ where $V\in\cal E$. This follows from the space being locally compact and Hausdorff. This way you would get $V=\bigcup_{x\in S}\overline{V(x)}$ and this union is countable as there are only countably many elements in $\cal E$.

Comment: How do i show that precompact neighbourhoods exist in $\cal E$?

Comment: @HenryW: Given an open set $U$ and a point $x\in U$, there is a compact neighborhood $K$ of $x$ such that $K\subseteq U$, by local compactness (unless your definition of local compactness is merely that every point has a compact neighborhood, let me know if that's the case). There is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ inside $K$ with $V\in\cal E$. Since $K$ is compact and $X$ is Hausdorff, $K$ is closed and thus contains the closure of $V$, which then is compact, being a closed subset of the compact set $K$.